# Problem installing nokogiri - "Package libxslt-dev is a virtual package"

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, nokogiri

I'm trying to install the nokogiri gem in ubuntu.  I've followed the instructions on this page: `http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html`

I've done the first steps ok:

```
# ruby developer packages
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev ruby1.8 ri1.8 rdoc1.8 irb1.8
sudo apt-get install libreadline-ruby1.8 libruby1.8 libopenssl-ruby
```

But when i try to do the next step, `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev`, i get this error:

```
Package libxslt-dev is a virtual package provided by:
libxslt1-dev 1.1.24-2ubuntu2
You should explicitly select one to install.
E: Package libxslt-dev has no installation candidate
```

I've no idea what this means, or how to select one (one of what?).  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Analyse your 'log':

```
Package libxslt-dev is a virtual package provided by:
libxslt1-dev 1.1.24-2ubuntu2
You should explicitly select one to install.
E: Package libxslt-dev has no installation candidate
```

Because that libxslt-dev is a virtual package, you have to install one of following packages (here, there is just one package named 'libxslt1-dev').

So, just tape :

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev
```

Comment: ah, i didn't read that properly - i didn't see the 1. Doh.  Thanks Sandro, that's fixed it.